# Modularity vs Performace with respect to ng-include in an angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Recently, I have been refactoring someone else's code. The requirement ( I'm not decision maker) is to break down large junk of html (around 1500 lines). I am porting the existing code to angular app.

I have little confusion with modularity v/s performance.

Exact problem with code:

There is main.html file which is 1500 lines. I have broke that file into
main_bar.html, main_content.html, main_map.html and main_locations.html.

Now main.html contains,

```
<div ng-include src="'views/main_bar.html'"/>
<div ng-include src="'views/main_content.html'"/>
<div ng-include src="'views/main_map.html'"/>
<div ng-include src="'views/main_locations.html'"/>
```

In app.js,

```
angular.module('ngBApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                controller: 'AboutCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
```

In MainCtrl,

```
'use strict';
angular.module('ngBApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   // some logic to fetch data and show
   // in different html chunks included via ng-include
  });
```

Although, this approach follows the modularity principle, doesn't it add overhead of downloading small junks of html with different http requests (with more header i.e, 4x header and other data) ?

Is there any other way to design app in angular way preserving performance and yet a modular code ?

Comment: What is the question? Yes, it downloads small chunks of html, and each HTTP connection (if it is to your server, vs. say a CDN) adds an overhead. Was this the question?

Comment: Really haven't defined a problem or what your performance issue is. What does `preserve performance` mean?

Comment: Withouth making multiple http requests which will slow down apps loading time.

Comment: You could render the html files into javascript templates while building your app. then you will have the modularity in dev and the performance in production.

Comment: Can you explain with example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way to design app in angular way preserving
>   performance and yet a modular code ?

Well, why not to use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to concatenate the resulting HTML file from pieces? Or you can even build resulting HTML [from template using includes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include).

I am strongly against using `ng-include`'s to break long html apart.

Comment: add present, I am using grunt, is there any grunt plugin to concatenate html ? I had look into grunt bake as of now, doesnt seem to work with ngInclude ?

Comment: @geekgugi There are many grunt plugins of such functionality. Search Github for `grunt include` and you will get many options like this: https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace